# Not Equals Query on Spring Boot REST/JPA Service

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, named-query

I'm brand new to Spring Boot, and I've created a very basic REST service that uses JPA, and exposes the RepositoryRestResource for CRUD and query operations on my model:

```java
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface CatalogueOrderRepository extends JpaRepository<CatalogueOrder, Long>,
    QuerydslPredicateExecutor<CatalogueOrder> {

}
```

Using this, I'm able to perform queries that involve searching for values, pagination, and ordering, for instance:

`?page=0&size=5&sort=priority,desc&orderStatus=submitted`

Is it possible to search for values that are not equal, without any additional work? For instance, all orders where the orderStatus is NOT equal to 'submitted'.

I notice that the `Predicate` interface has a `not()` method, though I'm not sure if it's related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try "Query creation from method names".

Let's say you want to search Orders by orderstatus <> submitted,

`List<Order> findByOrderstatusNot(String orderstatus);`

Comment: Will this also work with pagination/sorting? Would I need to also provide Sort and Pageable as parameters?

Comment: By sorting if you mean order by then yes you can use it Eg  
**findByOrderstatusOrderByOrderId**, but pagination is not going to be straightforward because that involves **limit** and **offset**.

Answer (score 1):

For such cases you should do some work. There are different approaches to do that. See Spring docs and examples about JPA.

E.g. you can use [`@Query`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query) or [specifications](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications).